# C++ multiple threads calling function issue

Tags: c++, multithreading, debugging, mutex

Need some help with this code. I created a function to print some debug text in my application ("debug" function). 2 threads (FD_READ and incDataProcess) are using this function to print some information within the debug window. When I run following code, the data is not displayed good, probably because the 2 thread are concurently accessing the function (data race). When I try to limit the access to the function at 1 thread at a time, using mutex, the program hangs. I don't understand why the program hangs when I protect the function with mutex. What am I doing wrong with my mutex ?

```
static mutex printMutex;
static mutex readQueueMutex;

//....

void debug(LPSTR text1, LPSTR text2, LPSTR text3)
{       

// printMutex.lock(); // the combination of lock - unlock 
//                       makes the program hang (solution 1)

//  lock_guard<mutex>_(printMutex); // Solution 2, the program
//                                     hangs also   

    char *Text1 = text1;
    char *Text2 = text2;
    char *Text3 = text3;
    char Text[2048];
    strcpy_s(Text, Text1);
    strcat_s(Text, Text2);
    strcat_s(Text, Text3);
    int TextLen = SendMessage(hDebug, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0);
    SendMessage(hDebug, EM_SETSEL, (WPARAM)TextLen, (LPARAM)TextLen);
    SendMessage(hDebug, EM_REPLACESEL, FALSE, (LPARAM)Text);

//  printMutex.unlock(); // See comment solution 1  
}

//.....

void incDataProcess(void *pBuffer)
{   
    debug("incDataThread launched\n", "", "");
    for(;;)
    {
        while (!readQueue.empty())
        {
            readQueueMutex.lock();
            string sReadBuffer = readQueue.front(); 
            readQueue.pop(); 
            readQueueMutex.unlock();

            string var;
            char *pVar = nullptr;                   
            char *next_token = nullptr;

            istringstream iss(sReadBuffer); // Put into a stream            

            while (getline(iss, var)) // Default delimiter '\n'
            {       
                pVar = _strdup(var.c_str()); // Cast string to char *                   

                if( strstr(pVar, "Qh57=") != NULL)
                {
                    char *label = strtok_s(pVar, "=", &next_token);     
                    char *pFoFd = strtok_s(NULL, "\n", &next_token);                            
                    strcpy_s(foFd, pFoFd);

                    debug("Qh57=", foFd, "\n");         
                }
            } //while getline
        } // while queue is not empty
    } // infinite for loop
}

//.....

case FD_READ:
{                       
    debug("FD_READ event\n", "", "");           

    int bytes_recv = recv(Socket, readBuffer, sizeof(readBuffer), 0);
    readQueueMutex.lock();
    readQueue.push(readBuffer);                     
    readQueueMutex.unlock();            

    char bytes[256];
    _itoa_s(bytes_recv, bytes, 10); 

    debug("Received ", bytes, " bytes from server\n")

    debug("End of FD_READ\n", "", "");

}
break;
```

Here is the debug window, without synchronization :

```
FD_READ event
Received 8 bytes from server
End of FD_READ
Qh57=0
FD_READ eventReceived 49 bytes from serverEnd of FD_READ // Display problem
                                                         // when second 
                                                         // thread calls the function
FD_READ event
Received 127 bytes from server
End of FD_READ
FD_READ event
Received 57 bytes from server
End of FD_READ
Qh57=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Brandon Kohn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31867759/68241) is the reason why you are getting a deadlock. As for a solution, I'd recommend you do something like the following:

```
static std::queue<std::string> pendingDebugMessages;
void debug(LPSTR text1, LPSTR text2, LPSTR text3)
{       
    lock_guard<mutex>_(printMutex);

    pendingDebugMessages.push(std::string());
    std::string& finalString = pendingDebugMessages.back();
    finalString = text1;
    finalString += text2;
    finalString += text3;
}

// Call this regularly from your message pump thread
void PrintPendingMessages()
{
    lock_guard<mutex>_(printMutex);
    while(!pendingDebugMessages.empty())
    {
        int TextLen = SendMessage(hDebug, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0);
        SendMessage(hDebug, EM_SETSEL, (WPARAM)TextLen, (LPARAM)TextLen);
        SendMessage(hDebug, EM_REPLACESEL, FALSE, (LPARAM)pendingDebugMessages.front().c_str());
        pendingDebugMessages.pop();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I would have suggested as well. +1

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

SendMessage blocks until the window processes the message. If that window was created on the other thread that also calls debug.. deadlock ensues.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have a sugestion ?